# What's more grammatically correct?

Tags: particle-が

Started learning Japanese two weeks ago and don't know which one is more natural.

雨が漸く止めた。

OR

雨漸くが止めた。

Comment: ようやく is usually written in kana.

Answer (score 1):

(One thing to note: やめる or とめる are not the correct choice of verb for rain stopping; that is やむ, past tense やんだ)

You cannot put an adverb like ようやく between a particle and the noun it connects too. There are two positions one can insert ようやく in this sentence: in the middle, and right before the verb.

ようやく雨が止んだ

雨がようやく止んだ

These two sentences are both correct, but not 雨ようやくが止んだ.